# Versioning Static Resources with Struts2 and Maven

Tags: java, maven, struts2, browser-cache, static-resource

I built a web application using Apache Struts2 and need to version static resources in order to enable caching inside browsers. I have all the resources checked into Subversion.

Is there a solution possible, such that Maven checks-out the static resources at the build time and reads the latest SVN revision number of a static file and accordingly add version number in it's URL and replace it inside the HTML templates using filter properties?

Comment: An alternative to your solution would be to use httpd/nginx in front of your servlet container. They will automatically handle caching using a combination of etag and last-modified headers.

Comment: Sure. Caching can be taken care of by the web server but browser anyways sends the request to see a no-change response which is one request wasted. To avoid this request, is to set Expires header, in which case, the image/js/css file needs to be renamed every time it is modified.

Comment: Yes ofcourse the browser will have to make a conditional GET. Though this issue can be mitigated with packing of static assests in a single bundle.